# php mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select the site_tags from my database based on clients site_id. IF the tag_id = 36 OR 37 they should NOT see the "choose background design" link. IF their tag_id does not equal 36 or 37 they should see the link....I have this code, but it's not working? Where am I going wrong here :( Thanks for all your assistance!

```
<?PHP
    /* Limit Template Selection to Premium Clients only */
    $id = $site->id;            
    $tags = mysql_query('SELECT tag_id FROM site_tags WHERE site_id = '.(int)$id);

    while ($tag = mysql_fetch_array($tags)){

        if ($tag['tag_id'] == '36' || $tag['tag_id'] == '37'){
            $link = "";
        } else {
            $link= "<h2>
                <a href=\"template.php\">Choose My Background Design</a>
                <a href=\"\" class=\"accordion\"><img class=\"info\" src=\"/img/info_icons/blue_off.png\" width=\"14\" height=\"15\" alt=\"\" title=\"More Information\"/></a>
            </h2>

            <div id=\"manage_te\" class=\"moreinfo\">
                <p>
                    Select a new website design to change the entire look &amp; feel of your website with just one click.
                </p>
            </div>";
        }
    }
    echo $link;
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean, it's not working? SQL Exception? No results? Wrong results?

Comment: Some friggin indentation please?!

Comment: I've fixed your SQL injection by the way (by typecasting id to integer using `(int)`).

Comment: @Christian Sciberras Although it is definitely good advice, I think it is a very bad idea to change the OP's code in the question, that might confuse people who try to solve the problem.

Comment: @jeroen - What if the OP changed it himself? Same outcome.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras No, I'll assume that the OP is posting the original code that has the problem. If you edit that code, you can inadvertently solve the problem or introduce other problems after which the question might not make sense anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you exclude those tags from the query?

```
SELECT tag_id FROM site_tags WHERE site_id = $id and tag_id not in (36,37)
```

Comment: Not to nitpick, but you tweaked it for performance and left it open for SQL injections?

Comment: @Christian Sciberra How do you not know that the variable $id was escaped for sql injection before this code that he posted?  nick rulez is only providing the answer.

Comment: You think someone that doesn't give a hoot about indentation would even think about sql injection? By the way, the OP didn't ask for any tweaking of any kind, so no, it's not the exact answer, though I gave it +1 for the initiative. Priorities, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

With limited info that you gave, I could only assume. So, my assumption is that when you fetch you will get multiple tags (which include tag_id=36 & tag_id=37). And since echo $link is outside the while loop, if you have other tag_ids (after 36 & 37) the $link with the string will be overwritten by the $link = "" (which is for the case other than tag_id=36 or 37). You might want to put your echo $link before the closing of the while loop like the following:

```
while ($tag = mysql_fetch_array($tags)){

   if ($tag['tag_id'] == '36' || $tag['tag_id'] == '37')
   {
       $link = ""; 
   }
   else
   {
       $link= "<h2><a href=\"template.php\">Choose My Background Design</a><a href=\"\"   class=\"accordion\"><img class=\"info\" src=\"/img/info_icons/blue_off.png\" width=\"14\" height=\"15\" alt=\"\" title=\"More Information\"/></a></h2>
<div id=\"manage_te\" class=\"moreinfo\">
<p>Select a new website design to change the entire look &amp; feel of your website with just one click.</p>    
</div>";
   }
   echo $link
}
```

Comment: If I move the echo $link into the while loop, I get multiple Choose Background Design links.

Answer (score 0):

Move `echo $link;` into cycle i think :)

Comment: If I move the echo $link into the while loop, I get multiple Choose Background Design links.

Answer (score 0):

It´s kind of hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code and knowing what exactly the problem is, but the obvious thing that is missing, is a [**database connection**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Comment: The db connection is included at the top of my file. I'm getting 0 results back, no errors.

Comment: @rob Are you sure you are getting 0 results back, or could it be that there are multiple results and `$link` gets overwritten (see @Osh Mansor's answer)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following approach would be cleaner:

```
<?php

$id = (int) $site->id;                
$r = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM site_tags WHERE site_id={$id} AND tag_id IN(36,37)");

if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    // the tag matched
} else {
    // no tag match
}
```

note the `int` cast done on the `$site->id` too that should prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) from being posssible.

Comment: I have about 80 tags that can be selected. I've tried your code, but it thinks it's matched anytime, if  36 or 37 is stored or if it has not been chosen and stored.